# Dehydrate the same field django

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a model `Student`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id                  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Name')
    lastname            = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Lastname')
    history             = HistoricalRecords()
```

Also I have a model:

```
class Class(models.Model):
        id                  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        student             = models.models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

my admin.py

```
class ClassResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ('student',)

    def dehydrate_student(self, Class):
        student= getattr(Class.student, "name")
        return '%s' % (student)


class ClassExportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, ClassAdmin):
    resource_class = ClassResource

admin.site.register(Class, ClassExportAdmin)
```

Now I am executing only `name`, is that possible to dehydrate the same field student one more time. I need past into my 2 column the surname of the student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export both `Student.name` and `Student.lastname` you can directly reference a Foreign Key relation in the `fields` parameter ([docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options)):

```py
class ClassResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ('student__name', 'student__lastname')
```

This means that the column names will appear in your export as:

- `student__name`
- `student__lastname`

If you want the name to be different, you can directly declare a field:

```py
    name = Field(
        column_name='name',
        attribute='name',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Student, 'name'))
```

This will then appear in the export under `name`.

Comment: yes, in two separate columns

Comment: ok - have updated my answer